# How to get daily number of emails under a label in gmail to google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Editing my question as requested.

I need to get the daily number of emails under a label in gmail to google sheets, in a way that I get the date and the number of emails per day (not including answers on the thread, just the first email received to be counted).

Sample:

[image: example]

Not my code, credit to @Suyash Gandhi

I tried using Suyash's code:

```
function CountEmail() {
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LabelName");
var labelname = label.getName();
var mails = label.getThreads();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var date = new Date();
sheet.appendRow([labelname,date,mails.length]);
}
```

But it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getName')
CountEmail  @ CountEmail.gs:4"

How can I make it work?

I am very new to this and don't fully understand how scripts can be edited, appreciate any help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `Attaching an image as an example:`. Can I ask you about the relationship between your sample image and your goal? And, about `I'm very new to scripts in google and would appreciate if I could get a step by step on how to do this.`, can I ask you about the detail of your expected answer?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   Note: stack overflow is not a coding service we are not going to do your work for you.

Comment: @DalmTo thank you for your comment, I edited the question to make it more appropriate. Could you please let me know if you can help me?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your comment, I edited the question to make it more appropriate. Could you please let me know if you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provides Date,Count,list of subjects and sorts the output list by date and displays in on a sheet

```
function CountEmail() {
  const ts = GmailApp.search("label: ");//update label
  let obj = {pA:[]}
  ts.forEach(t => { 
    let s = t.getFirstMessageSubject();
    let dt = t.getMessages()[0].getDate();
    let p = `${dt.getFullYear()}~${dt.getMonth()+1}~${dt.getDate()}`
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      obj[p] = {date:p,subject:[s],count:1};
      obj.pA.push(p);
    } else {
      obj[p].subject.push(s);
      obj[p].count = Number(obj[p].count) + 1;
    }
  });
  let o = obj.pA.map(p => {
    return [obj[p].date,obj[p].count,obj[p].subject.join('\n')];
  });
  o.sort((a,b) => {
    let ta = a[0].split('~');
    let tb = b[0].split('~');
    let va = new Date(ta[0],ta[1],ta[2]);
    let vb = new Date(tb[0],tb[1],tb[2]);
    return va - vb;
  })
  o.unshift(['Date','Count','Subjects'])
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//update sheet
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping out, but i'm still getting the same error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')
CountEmail @ Code.gs:28

Comment: I tested it on my account and it works for me.  Since I don't have you account I can't reproduce the problem so it would be impossible for me to debug the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I am doing: goggle sheet > apps script > + script > pasting code provided > update label and sheet names > save > run. Then I get the error above. Could you please advise on how I should proceed?

Comment: May be you need to change the sheet names and update the search pattern also

Comment: I just copied it back into my account and ran it again with the same pattern and it works fine.  It's finding over five hundred emails.

Comment: you were correct, after changing the sheet name, it kinda worked. The issue is, it is not pulling the data from a specific label, it is pulling emails containing the word. > GmailApp.search("label: ");//update label < Whatever word I put in here, it searches it on my gmail and adds it to the sheet. Is there a way of pulling the emails from a specific label?

Comment: Well then I guess your search pattern must be incorrect.  I generally copy the exact search pattern from the Gmail UI

Comment: You were correct again! I changed the label name in both gmail and the code and now it works perfectly! Thank you soooooooo much!

Comment: I just noticed the date from the email in the sheets has something wrong, if I received an email today, it pulls to the sheet as 16th from November, not December as it should. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I made a small tweak perhaps that will work

Comment: It worked like magic now! THANK YOU SO MUCH!